# Kotlin type hinting an Interface in function parameter to receive any object of class that implemented the Interface

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, kotlin, generics

In Kotlin with Spring Boot 3, I am trying to implement a pattern where in the controller, I'll receive a RequestDto as `@RequestBody`, which has implemented an Interface `DtoInterface` and I will pass this dto to my Service. The `create` function of the service has TypeHinted the `DtoInterface` and any Dto Class that implemented this interface can be passed there.

In my current implementation, I can't access the property of the dto from the service.

**Controller**

```kotlin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/brands")
class BrandController (private val service: BrandService){
    @PostMapping("/")
    fun postCreate(@RequestBody brandCreateRequestDto: BrandCreateRequestDto): String
    {
        val test = service.create(brandCreateRequestDto);
        return test
    }
}
```

**BrandCreateRequestDto**

```kotlin
import com.example.api.dto.DtoInterface

data class BrandCreateRequestDto (
    val name: String,
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    val slug: String,
    val body: String,
    val status: String,
):DtoInterface
```

**DtoInterface**

```kotlin
interface DtoInterface {}
```

Now from my BrandService, I want to type hint this `DtoInteface` to create a function, but here `name` is not available in `data` object.

**BrandService**

```kotlin
@Service
class BrandService (){
    fun create(data: DtoInterface): String {     
        return "Name: " + data.name
    }
}
```

I used a similar pattern in PHP and works perfectly. I assume the syntax here in Kotlin is different, but can't find any similar solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DtoInterface` has no properties. If you only know that an object implements the `DtoInterface`, nothing guarantees that the object has a `name` property.

For instance, here is a class that also implements the `DtoInterface`:

```kotlin
data class Square(val sideLength: Int): DtoInterface
```

Passing `Square(42)` to your service must be allowed because it implements the `DtoInterface`. But in that case you see that trying to call `data.name` on this one will just fail. This is something we know at compile time so the compiler doesn't allow it.

Usually the point of using an interface is to define a set of common properties that you can guarantee on subclasses. If you add the `name` property to the `DtoInterface`, any subclass will *have to* define this property:

```kotlin
interface DtoInterface {
    val name: String
}

data class BrandCreateRequestDto (
    override val name: String,
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    val slug: String,
    val body: String,
    val status: String,
) : DtoInterface
```

With these definitions, the service can call the `data.name` property because we can be sure that all subclasses have this property. You can see with the `override` keyword that this property comes from a supertype.

Now, maybe `name` shouldn't be considered a common property in your case. If so, an alternative is to simply declare the `BrandCreateRequestDto` as input to your service method, which would solve the problem:

```kotlin
@Service
class BrandService (){
    fun create(data: BrandCreateRequestDto): String {     
        return "Name: " + data.name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Joffrey's answer, you can also make use of Kotlin's [smart cast feature](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html):

```
@Service
class BrandService (){
    fun create(data: DtoInterface): String {     
        if (data is BrandCreateRequestDto) {
            return "Name: " + data.name
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```